# Crashing bug in iOS8 with UICollectionview, related to UIApplicationAccessibility

Tags: uicollectionview, ios8

I have an app that displays a UICollectionView on a page, this works fine in iOS7 but crashes hard in iOS8 with a tracelog that points to UICollectionViewAccessibility and UIApplicationAccessibility, even though I have no code that touches Accessibility at all.

I have managed to isolate the problem and put up a small app that reproduces the crash here.

http://github.com/beno/ios8bug

I find it hard to comprehend that code with this kind of glaring bug would ship, but it looks like it did. I have filed a bug with Apple, but no response so far. Any help with more info or a workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Sample trace:

```
Thread 1Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x0343d385 in CFHash ()
#1  0x0109c264 in NSKeyValueAccessorHash ()
#2  0x03436373 in CFBasicHashFindBucket ()
#3  0x0346294b in CFSetGetValue ()
#4  0x0109f316 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] ()
#5  0x10ba246e in -[NSObject(UIAccessibilitySafeCategory) safeValueForKey:] ()
#6  0x10d1f359 in -[UICollectionViewAccessibility _accessibilityDescendantElementAtIndexPathIsValid:] ()
#7  0x10d1f376 in -[UICollectionViewAccessibility _accessibilityDescendantElementAtIndexPathIsValid:] ()
#8  0x10d1f376 in -[UICollectionViewAccessibility _accessibilityDescendantElementAtIndexPathIsValid:] ()
#9  0x10d1f376 in -[UICollectionViewAccessibility _accessibilityDescendantElementAtIndexPathIsValid:] ()
#10 0x10d1f376 in -[UICollectionViewAccessibility _accessibilityDescendantElementAtIndexPathIsValid:] ()
#11 0x10d1f376 in -[UICollectionViewAccessibility _accessibilityDescendantElementAtIndexPathIsValid:] ()
#12 0x10d1f376 in -[UICollectionViewAccessibility _accessibilityDescendantElementAtIndexPathIsValid:] ()
#13 0x10d1f376 in -[UICollectionViewAccessibility _accessibilityDescendantElementAtIndexPathIsValid:] ()
#14 0x10d1f376 in -[UICollectionViewAccessibility _accessibilityDescendantElementAtIndexPathIsValid:] ()
#15 0x10d1f376 in -[UICollectionViewAccessibility _accessibilityDescendantElementAtIndexPathIsValid:] ()
#16 0x10d1f376 in -[UICollectionViewAccessibility _accessibilityDescendantElementAtIndexPathIsValid:] ()
....
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this, the bug is a regression flaw in Accessibility which acts up this way when the view is it's own delegate (like I had it configured). So use a different delegate is the answer.